# How to use Java to process Webcam data as Image immediately in Webpage

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, web

So I have a webpage. I want to catch a webcam data and processing the image I get from that. I thought I could get the image from webcam with WebRTC in javascript. The thing is that, the library I found most suitable with the image processing I need is in Java. It reads an image and do the processing.

How do I combine this? Get image from webcam using WebRTC in javascript and processing it using Java? Or is there any other way to do this?

If my question's wrong, please tell me why. If you think I ask this in a wrong site, please also tell me where I should ask this. Thank you.

**Note**
As I'm new to web programming, searching and searching, I found that the practice is to execute JSP in server. But what if I have to process the image continously? Won't it be so slow since I would have to send the data continously? Though, in this case, I just need to practice it locally, not in real server. But, is there any way to execute Java in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture individual images over a period of time utilizing a WebRTC recording Javascript library. You can then send the images or the blob down over a websocket to your Java websocket server and process the images.

Check [this out](http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv), this should pretty much give you all the tools you need to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: It's a really good tutorial, but the problem is, like I've said I'm new to web programming, till now, I can't figure out at all how to use Jetty...

Comment: @zargin, you want to modify individual images in the code behind for a webpage. You need to send the data somehow and one of the many ways(and possibly the simplest) is through a websocket. There are a TON of websocket servers out there but jetty is just one that happens to be in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I still have trouble here and there, but true this tutorial is the one I need to compose all of that. Thank you Sir!